# Magento Missing Orders

Tags: magento-1.9

I am having a serious issue with Magento and I don't know where to begin troubleshooting. I had about 40 orders come through my site on Sunday (7/12/15). When I logged in yesterday morning I saw the orders and printed all of them out for shipment (order numbers 100001511 to 100001540). When I logged back into my site today all of those orders have been deleted and there are new orders replacing 1512, 1513, 1515, 1516. I have reviewed my payment processors (authorize.net and paypal) and have cleared payments for orders 1511 - 1540 and duplicated cleared payments for orders 1512, 1513, 1515, 1516. The second orders for 1512, 1513, 1515, and 1516 are shown in my orders list but the original orders for these numbers as well as orders 1517-1540 are no where to be found in magento.

The only changes that were made to my site yesterday was the linking of the website to Shipstation which was installed through magento connect. I reached out to Shipstation and they replied saying that it couldn't have been there software as they don't send any signals to Magento that could delete orders.

If you could help me diagnose this issue it would be greatly appreciated. I have no idea how it happened or where to begin on diagnosing what caused it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you really need a software engineer or consultant which fixes this for you. In Magento is no way to delete orders, therefore some third party module has done this or they were even deleted directly in the database.

This could be a restored backup, too. I don't know any magento module for deleting orders which restores the increment id too.

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if your server is on a VM platform. I'm almost willing to bet that if tis is the case, the server was restored to an earlier snapshot - the other possibility is a database restore. These are the only scenarios that immediately comes to mind that could explain this.